# Android structured styles: drawable resource grouping by style

Tags: android, android-resources, android-styles

I have listView with thumbnails. Some of list items should be disabled. So, I would like to create a style to referenced from code, when user is logged in then these items are enabled.

How to name/place drawable resources?

```
/res/drawable/item1_enable
/res/drawable/item1_disable
/res/drawable/item2_enable
/res/drawable/item2_disable
```

It is not very nice way when there are more drawables which could be disabled. Is there a way to place it to structure based on style? EDIT: Is there any way how to group resources by style? What is prefered way to do.

```
/res/drawable/item1
/res/drawable/item2
/res/drawable-styleDisable/item1
/res/drawable-styleDisable/item2
/res/drawable-styleEnable/item1
/res/drawable-styleEnable/item2
```

My second related question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933441/android-structured-styles-selector

Comment: I think you have read this first : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: I read. That is why I thing that I missed something, and that is why Iam asking. It seems to me as a quite common problem. So, there is problably better way to solve it...

Comment: I think you can not define custom drawable qualifier like drawable-yourstylename/item.

Comment: I am SURE it is not possible. It is what the question is about. Is there some ANOTHER way? How to structure resources based on style.

Comment: There is no way to structure resources based on style.